# Why is my validation accuracy stuck around 65% and how do i increase it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm making an image classification CNN with 5 classes with each having 693 images with a width and height of 224px using VGG16, but my validation accuracy is stuck after 15-20 epochs around 60% - 65%.

I'm already using some data augmentation, batch normalization, and dropout and I have frozen the first 5 layers but I can't seem to increase my accuracy more than 65%.

these are my own layers

```py
img_rows, img_cols, img_channel = 224, 224, 3

base_model = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channel))
for layer in base_model.layers[:5]:
    layer.trainable = False

add_model = Sequential()
add_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]))
add_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
add_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
add_model.add(BatchNormalization())
add_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
add_model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=add_model(base_model.output))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

and this is my dataset with my model

```py
batch_size = 64
epochs = 25

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=30,
        width_shift_range=.1,
        height_shift_range=.1, 
        horizontal_flip=True)
train_datagen.fit(x_train)


history = model.fit_generator(
    train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    callbacks=[ModelCheckpoint('VGG16-transferlearning.model', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True)]
)
```

I want to get a higher accuracy because what I get now is just not enough so any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: We need more informations in order to help you, how are you loading the weights ? are you freezing some layer ? what is the shape of your inputs images ?  etc

Comment: What is your accuracy on a different model?  Try resnet or inception.

Comment: What were you doing for your data augmentation, image rotation?  Was your data set size really only  693?  What happened when you varied Dropout?  What happened when you changed the size of the existing layers?  What happened when you got rid of layers or added layers?  What is the complexity of the images?

Comment: Also that looks like a very limited set of augmentation.  Experiment with many more augmentations, including color/blur/noise/crop/higher level of rotation, etc.  Go beyond what you think is reasonable, and see how it trains.  You'd be surprised how much it can help.  Then tune it back a bit if it's too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you can try are:

- Reduce your batch size.
- Choose another optimizer: [RMSprop](https://keras.io/optimizers/#rmsprop), [SGD](https://keras.io/optimizers/#sgd)...
- Increase the learning rate by default and then use the callback [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau)

But, as usual, it depends on the data you are using. Are well balanced?